# Por que se usa display: block; nos links? tag "a", para fazer a barra de navegação?

Tags: html, css, menu, link, display

```
ul li a{ display: block; }
```

Por que precisa colocar os *links* com *display block* ao fazer os menus?

Comment: Esse atributo não é obrigatório, você pode adicionar um *ul li a* sem o display block.

Comment: Não precisa....

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso não precisa. A tag de listas já tem o display: block; por padrão salvo me engano. No caso do block não é obrigatório a não ser que você queira de alguma forma um menu na vertical acho eu.

A diferença seria por `li{ display: inline;}`, pois você vai mudar a disposição dos itens da lista para que fique um ao lado do outro(horizontal).

Acho que é isso. Enfim, espero ter ajudado.